# If I shift a curve in the normal direction, are its tangent vectors also shifted by parallel transport?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, submanifold

I'm in the following situation:

Let $\Sigma^{n-1}$ be a hyper-surface of a riemannian manifold $M^n$ and $\nu:\Sigma\to T\Sigma$ is a vector field normal to $\Sigma$ with $|\nu(p)|=r>0, \forall p\in \Sigma$. Let $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to \Sigma$ with $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=u\in T_p\Sigma$.

> Is it true that
> $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0\exp_{\alpha(t)}[\nu(\alpha(t))]=P_{\gamma}(u),$$
> where $\gamma(s)=\exp_p(s\nu(p))$ is the geodesic going out from $p$ with vector $\nu(p)$ and $P_{\gamma}(u)$ is the parallel transport of $u$ along $\gamma$ from $\gamma(0)=p$ to $\gamma(1)$?

If so, how do I compute this?

EDIT: It seems it is false: take $\alpha(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, 0)$ on the unit sphere $\Sigma=\mathbb{S}^2$ into $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\nu(p)$ the outward normal vector, so $\nu(p)=p$. Then $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0\exp_{\alpha(t)}[\nu(\alpha(t))]=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_02\alpha(t)=2u$, which *is not* the parallel transport of $u$ referred above.

So, what would be the correct answer?

Comment: What is the derivative of the exponential map $\exp:TM\to M$ on a riemannian manifold? Here I'm considering the exponential as a map of two variables, $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, so the base point is not fixed...